# How to add function result to <p> tag in Django

Tags: python, html, django, function

I am trying to print the results of a function I have into a `<p>` tag once a button on that same HTML page has been clicked. I am working within a Django web application as well.

Here is my function:

```
def Question_Init():

Beginning_Question_Prompts = ("Who","Whom","What","Where","When","Why","Which",
    "Whose","How","Was","Were","Did","Do","Does")
Ending_Question_Prompts = ("?",":","...")
questions = []

text1 = open('/Users/joshuablew/Documents/myCorpus/version1.txt').read()

textList = sent_tokenize(text1)

for sentence in textList:
    if sentence.startswith(Beginning_Question_Prompts):
        questions.append(sentence)

    if sentence.endswith(Ending_Question_Prompts):
        questions.append(sentence)

return questions
```

I want to add the results of this function - which is the "questions" list - into the paragraph tag here:

```
<div class="content">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Show Questions</button>
  <p>#Where I want the results of Question_Init() to go</p>
</div>
```

What must I do to the button attributes for this to happen? Should this be done with Javascript? Or can it be done some other way?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: return the `questions` to the html page as context and place it in between `<p>` and for displaying on button click, I would recommend using simple **Bootstrap Modal**

Comment: @Bijoy, What exactly do you mean by context? And how would I go about returning "questions" to the html page?

Comment: It really doesn't matter what the function is, does it? Rewrite your question with the function `def Question_Init(): return "Hello"`, and the problem will be a lot clearer.

Comment: I mean here context means your questions return the `questions` to the html page and use a for-loop `{% for question in questions %}` and then `<p>{{ question }}</p>`  to display each question, display it only when button is clicked by using **JS**

Comment: Gonna remove the `nltk` tag since it's really a `django` question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might find useful to write your own custom template tag. You can find more information with examples [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags)

First of all, you should create place, where custom tags will be stored. 
You should add to your app directory package `templatetags` (directory with `__init__.py`)
Then create file for tag, for example `csv_content.py`

In that file define your tag:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def csv_content():
    html_result='' 
    #define path to your csv file
    csv_path = 'test.csv'

    text1 = open(csv_path).read()

    textList = sent_tokenize(text1)

    for sentence in textList:
      #you probably want some styling here
      html_result += '<p>{}</p>'.format(sentence)

    return html_result
```

Then in your template you can use your tag like `{% csv_content %}`

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks so much, I was able to find a tutorial for custom template tags on Treehouse.com and it worked great.

Comment: @jblew awesome! Glad that you figured out how to deal with this issue. Feel free to chose this answer as correct one :)

Comment: This answer is 3 words away ("custom template tag") from being a "link-only answer", which is a big no-no on this site. Next week djangoproject.com might redesign their site, and your "here" link will be next to useless. You can improve your answer (and the site content) by writing at least a minimal answer from the contents of the link.

Comment: @alexis thanks, I've added description of how-to create own tag